# Alternative to Timeout notification node in IBM Integration Bus

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

*I probably have found a similar question (and answer) but I wanted to know if any better alternative is available.*

Link to similar question:

> > http://mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=72601&sid=f62d9730d61ee2ee2a59986dd79defd1

I want to schedule a particular message flow every 5 seconds (or so). I'm using IIB 10 and it's not associated with MQ. So, Timer nodes are non functional.

I've read about scheduling it with **cronjob** but again it's getting dependent on the OS which is not my preference. Is there any alternative to the timeout notification node?

Can we use java.util.TimerTask or something similar to to it? Any helping hands please?

Comment: Please provide a link to the similar question, as this will help reviewers not providing the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any solution that does not require a cron job or other external scheduler.

Many organisations use a distributed scheduler like Ctrl-M for a wide range of tasks, and adding a couple of jobs to support the integration layer is not seen as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own timer flow using an infinite WHILE loop with SLEEP and PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL functions and sending HTTP requests or configure a "CallableFlow".

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea @Igor. I don't think _infinite loop_ a good option. I've noticed the CPU usage increases a lot handling such loops. I solved my issue with a small **UDN**. The only issue I'm facing right now is, my UDN is not detecting the properties value no matter what I do. Hopefully I'll fix that by tomorrow.

Comment: Did you have a sleep? With no sleep it would consume CPU, put in a reasonable sleep to prevent.

Comment: Yes, I used thread.sleep(x * 1000) where x was the user defined property of the node. The node works perfectly! 